# Teams Underlying SharePoint Site Settings - How to Prohibit Sharing Site and Files

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I want to prohibit Teams users in the members & visitor permission groups from sharing the site as well as sharing individual files.

I have a Teams site where I am a site owner.  If I go to a channel, click the files tab, then open in SharePoint, I can view the SharePoint site files in a browser.

To attempt to prohibit site and file sharing, I tweaked the SharePoint site settings as follows: Settings > Site Permissions > Access Requests Settings

Uncheck box for: "SharePoint access request settings allow members to share the site and individual files" which also automatically on checks the box below it.

[image]

After successfully performing this task, I was surprised to know that both teams site owners and members can still go to the underlying SharePoint site in a browser and share the site and individual files.

[image]

What action must I take as a site owner to prohibit sharing this site as well as individual files?

Answer (score 0):

The Team SharePoint site is a SharePoint site collection, you can turn off external sharing at the site collection level, but you need to have access to the SharePoint admin panel in O365 to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have admin access to the site collection site settings but how do I access the SharePoint admin panel in O365 to make the changes?